# Which enemies can be slagged and which cannot be slagged?

Tags: borderlands-2

What are the enemies that are impossible to slag?

For example, are you able to slag

- The Warrior
- Saturn
- Vermivorous The Invincible
- Terramorphous The Invincible

Comment: I know Terramorphous can be slagged, but he usually resists it, and it only lasts about one second.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot say that I have ever managed/bothered to slag Saturn, but some larger bosses - like BNK-3R (aka bunker) and the Warrior - will get slagged without showing a graphic (turning purple). They still take the increased damage, but you only know they are slagged because their health suddenly falls much easier. These bosses tend to shake off that slag much faster than normal mobs however, so you will just have to judge when it wears off based on your damage output.

Terramorphous can be slagged, and will show it (turn purple) but he has serious resistance so you will need a high slag % chance weapon; and the slag does NOT last long (2 seconds tops). Your best bet in single player is to use slag granades (slag bouncing betty's tend to be best, as each projectile they fire has a slag chance and they spray tons of them), and use your best DPS gun to do all you can in that 2 seconds he is slagged. In co-op have one person use a high slag % chance (the "Slagga" SMG does well) and the other player(s) stick to DPS.

Vermi is essentially slag-proof. You MAY manage to slag him with a 70% slag chance sniper rifle or alike, but the slag wears off nearly instantly. I would say get his attention on a crystalisk and then back waaaaaaaay off and hope to avoid aggro... well, that or get him in Tundra Express and get the train to hit him. That's always good for a laugh.

To my knowlege, the only "slag-proof" enemies in the game are mobs that already have "slagged" in their name (ex: slagged stalker, slagged spiderant, slagged rakk, and maybe the Slag Dragon (Boost?) in Tina's DLC), and (aside from that dragon) they tend to have pretty poor hp and defense so just mow 'em down with a fire wep and move on.

Comment: Bouncing Betties are the ones that pop up into the air before exploding. Did you mean MIRVs, which break into smaller grenades first?

Comment: Betties do pop up when the fuse runs out, BUT they also bounce around firing dozens of tiny bullet-like projectiles in a 360 degree around them as they bounce. Any elemental effect on the granade is added to each of these projectiles, so if the granade were to have say: 30% chance to cause slag (It is not listed on the granade, I know, but i', posing a hypothetical), EACH of those small projectiles has a 30% chance, and it fires dozens before exploding itself; hence a virtually 100% chance to slag a large target like terramorphous.